# Strategy not entering trades or exiting based off time format

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to develop a strategy that will

- Enter trades at 00:00
- Get the previous days price range from 20:00 to 20:45
- If difference is negative enter a long position, if difference is positive enter a short position
- Then exit the recently opened position at 23:59

```
// © Daltonico
//@version=4
strategy("DTCC Basis Predictor", overlay=true)

// This variable will store the result of the trade (long or short)
var tradeDirection = "none"

// Combine the hour and minute to get the current time in the "hhmm" format
hourCombined = hour * 100 + minute

if hourCombined  == 0000
    prevPrice20 = timestamp(year(time), month(time), dayofmonth(time) - 1, 20, 0, 0)
    prevPrice2045 = timestamp(year(time), month(time), dayofmonth(time) - 1, 20, 45, 0)

    // Check if the price range from 20:00 to 20:45 was negative
    if (prevPrice2045  - prevPrice20) < 0
        // If the price range was negative, take a long position
        tradeDirection := "long"
    else
        // If the price range was positive, take a short position
        tradeDirection := "short"

// Check if the current time is 23:59
if hourCombined == 2359
    // Close out the trade
    tradeDirection := "none"

// Calculate the performance of the strategy
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=tradeDirection == "long")
strategy.close("Long", when=tradeDirection == "none")
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=tradeDirection == "short")
strategy.close("Short", when=tradeDirection == "none")
```

I've tried trying to print the time in a console.logger() type way but no luck. Any advice on why its not entering if the time format is off or if the "time" is not the right approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error here :

```
prevPrice20 = timestamp(year(time), month(time), dayofmonth(time) - 1, 20, 0, 0)
```

Gives you a timestamp, not the value of the bar at this time.
The you compare the two timestamp (thinking you compare values of the bar).

You should use the V5 version of pinescript and then put your strategy.enter and strategy.exit inside if block.